# How to implement google like pagination in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, pagination

I am using the repeater and following code for populating page numbers. It is used for accomplishing pagination in gridview.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager"   OnItemDataBound="rptPager_ItemDataBound"  runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage"   runat="server" Text = '<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' Enabled = '<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick = "Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>                                  


      public void PopulatePager()
    {
        int recordCount = TotalPages;
        if (PageSizeChanged != null)
        {
            HiddenField hd = new HiddenField();

            int current;
            current = PageIndex;
            int pre;
            int Next;
            double dblPageCount = (double)((decimal)recordCount / decimal.Parse(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue));
            int pageCount = TotalPages;

            List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
            if (pageCount > 0)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", PageIndex > 1));
                current = PageIndex;
                pre = --PageIndex;
                PageIndex = current;

                pages.Add(new ListItem("Previous", pre.ToString(), PageIndex > 1));

                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                }
                int currentPage = PageIndex;
                Next = ++PageIndex;
                PageIndex = currentPage;
                pages.Add(new ListItem("Next", Next.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));
                pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", pageCount.ToString(), PageIndex < pageCount));

                hd.Value = (pre.ToString());


            }
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();  

        }
    }
```

It works fine!!! Now I want to implement google like pagination. It should show specific set of 10 numbers, when it reaches to the end number then it should show another set of 10 numbers. I am not able to tweak the above function in order to meet this requirement.

Please help !!!

Comment: To start with dont add all the pages to the list which you are binding,Add only 10 items. Then on the eventhandler on the pager check if you are on the end page then clear the list and add the next set of pages.

Comment: Can you please provide code for my better understanding...

Comment: Please try modifying the above code as per my suggestion  and let me know where you get stuck

Comment: which event handler should I use for removing items....

Comment: On  `Page_Changed` event from your LinkButton. There you know what page you are currently in .So if it is the endpage clear the list